# How can set the height and the width of original image when I use the Fotorama control?

Tags: jquery, css, fotorama

I use the Fotorama control at http://fotorama.io/customize/thumbnails/

The document tell me I can adjust the height and the width of thumbnail by set

```
 <img src="1_thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96">
```

Now I hope to set the height and the width of original image 1.jpg, but the code `<a href="image/1.jpg" style="display:block; width:100px; height:200px;">` don't work.

```
<div class="fotorama"  data-nav="thumbs">
  <a href="1.jpg"><img src="1_thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
  <a href="2.jpg"><img src="2_thumb.jpg" width="64" height="128"></a>
  <a href="3.jpg"><img src="3_thumb.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, it say's "By default, thumbnail is a 64×64 square. Adjust this with data-thumb-width and data-thumb-height."

Comment: I can adjust the height and the width of thumbnai, but I can't adjust the height and the width of  original image

Answer (score 0):

You can only adjust the size of entire Fotorama with several attributes:

- `data-width`
- `data-ratio`
- `data-min-width`
- `data-max-width`
- `data-min-height`
- `data-max-height`

http://fotorama.io/customize/dimensions/

So try this:

```
<div class="fotorama"
     data-width="100"
     data-height="200"
     data-nav="thumbs">
```

And you have some options to fit an image into a fotorama: http://fotorama.io/customize/fit/.

That should be enough to control the size of the images.